# Translation invariance in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, symmetry, field-theory, interactions

In P&S's QFT book, page 213, the book considered Heisenberg operator's translation under General interacting field:
$$ \begin{aligned}
\left\langle\Omega|\phi(x)| \lambda_{\mathbf{p}}\right\rangle &=\left\langle\Omega\left|e^{i P \cdot x} \phi(0) e^{-i P \cdot x}\right| \lambda_{\mathbf{p}}\right\rangle \\
&=\left.\left\langle\Omega|\phi(0)| \lambda_{\mathbf{p}}\right\rangle e^{-i p \cdot x}\right|_{p^0=E_{\mathbf{p}}} \\
&=\left.\left\langle\Omega|\phi(0)| \lambda_0\right\rangle e^{-i p \cdot x}\right|_{p^0=E_{\mathbf{p}}} .
\end{aligned} \tag{7.4}$$

Also, in Weinberg's book page 458, when he introducing The Källen-Lehmann Representation, he gives the similar formula

$$\begin{aligned}
&\langle 0|\Phi(x)| n\rangle=\exp \left(i p_n \cdot x\right)\langle 0|\Phi(0)| n\rangle \\
&\left\langle n\left|\Phi^{\dagger}(y)\right| 0\right\rangle=\exp \left(-i p_n \cdot y\right)\left\langle n\left|\Phi^{\dagger}(0)\right| 0\right\rangle
\end{aligned} \tag{10.7.2}$$

My question is why in general interacting picture, we can transform the $\Phi(x)$ in above way?

In free field, P&S proved this transformation in page 26:
$$ e^{-i \mathbf{P} \cdot \mathbf{x}} a_{\mathbf{p}} e^{i \mathbf{P} \cdot \mathbf{x}}=a_{\mathbf{p}} e^{i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}}, \quad e^{-i \mathbf{P} \cdot \mathbf{x}} a_{\mathbf{p}}^{\dagger} e^{i \mathbf{P} \cdot \mathbf{x}}=a_{\mathbf{p}}^{\dagger} e^{-i \mathbf{p} \cdot \mathbf{x}} \tag{2.48}$$
and therefore
$$ \begin{aligned}
\phi(x) &=e^{i(H t-\mathbf{P} \cdot \mathbf{x})} \phi(0) e^{-i(H t-\mathbf{P} \cdot \mathbf{x})} \\
&=e^{i P \cdot x} \phi(0) e^{-i P \cdot x}
\end{aligned} \tag{2.49}$$

While in interacting field, we may cannot write field as creation and annihilation operators.

By the way, it seems that the field operator transformation law in Weinberg's book have a sign difference with P&S, ($\phi(x)=e^{-i P \cdot x} \phi(0) e^{i P \cdot x}$) is this right?

Comment: Weinberg uses a different sign convention for the Minkowski metric ($\mathrm{d}{s}^2=-\text{d}{t}^2+\text{d}{x}^2+\text{d}{y}^2+\text{d}{z}^2$), which is conventional in general relativity and string theory. P&S uses the standard particle physics/QFT sign convention, which differs from the above by a factor of $-1$.

Answer (score 5):

I consider the spacetime translation covariance property ($\phi(x) = \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i} x\cdot P} \phi(0) \mathrm{e}^{-\mathrm{i} x\cdot P}$) as fundamental in QFTs on Minkowski spacetime (as e.g. in the [Wightman axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wightman_axioms) of QFT). This definitely makes sense because translations are symmetries on Minkowski spacetime and symmetry transformations should not change predictions of the theory. Thus, we assume that there are some unitary operators $U(x)$, $x\in\mathbb{R}^4$, that implement translations on quantum fields:
$$U(x) \phi(y) U(x)^* = \phi(y+x), \ y \in\mathbb{R}^4.$$
By [Stone's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%27s_theorem_on_one-parameter_unitary_groups), the unitaries $U(x)$ have self-adjoint generators that we call $P = (H,\mathbf{P})$, i.e. $U(x) = \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x\cdot P} = \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}x_0H - \mathrm{i} \mathbf{x} \cdot \mathbf{P}}$. Using some other properties of QFTs (positivity of energy, causality, etc.) it turns out that the choice of $P$ is essentially unique.

In classical mechanics, Noether's theorem relates symmetries to conservation laws, e.g. spacetime translation symmetry is related to conservation of energy-momentum. Therefore, it is more than reasonable to call the generators $P$ the energy-momentum operators. Basically you can say that the energy-momentum operator is defined via the spacetime translation covariance property.